# Returning the error cannot read property 'setstate' of undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Why can't I set the state to a state variable which I already defined in the state, I also tried to set state as `this.state.propval = response.data`.

State declaration,

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
     propval:null,
        };
    }
```

Sending the axios request and getting the response here.

```
 axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
    .then(function (response) {
      alert(response.data)
      var result = response.data
      console.log("result out :"+result)
      this.setState({propval : result})
      this.propfun(response.data)
      self.forceUpdate()
    })
```

But getting the error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/forms/neweventcreation.js:306
  303 | alert(response.data)
  304 | var result = response.data
  305 | console.log("result out :"+result)
> 306 | this.setState({propval : result})
  307 | 
  308 | this.propfun(response.data)
  309 | self.forceUpdate()
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem. `this` in the `axios.then()` refers to the local scope.

seems you have already added a global reference with the variable `self`

try this

```
let that = this; //global scope
axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
.then(function (response) {
  //this referes to the current function scope.
  alert(response.data)
  var result = response.data
  console.log("result out :"+result)
  that.setState({propval : result}) // or self.setState({propval : result})
  that.propfun(response.data)  //or self.propfun(response.data) 
  self.forceUpdate()
})
```

read this article to learn more javascript [scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

Comment: I would suggest you to use arrow function. We are not recommended to assign this to a local variable and use which is very ugly or doing direct binding. Best to go with arrow function

Answer (score 3):

This isn't working because `this` is different inside of axios. `this` inside axios refers to the axios object, not your react component.

If you use ES6, you would want to use arrow functions (which don't have their own `this`). [Learn more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
 axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
    .then((response) => {
      alert(response.data)
      var result = response.data
      console.log("result out :"+result)
      this.setState({propval : result})
      this.propfun(response.data)
      self.forceUpdate()
    })
```

If you are not using ES6, you would do it like :

```
var self = this;
axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
   .then(function (response) {
   ...
   self.setState({propval : result})
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the function where you have done axios post call. Or you can make that function anonymous. For eg:

```
postData(){
   .... axios call
}
```

becomes

```
postData = () => {
     ... axios call
}
```

Comment: If you downvote something atleast tell the reason, no point in explaining stuff

Comment: I didn’t down vote your answer. The reason your answer is wrong because the OP has issue in axios post request because.then he uses regular function where he don’t get this context inside the function so either he has to assign this to a local variable and use that variable to do setState or bind that function in .then or use arrow function. But you suggested to bind the function where he placed axios post request which isn’t correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because in **es5** `this` is refers to **object** on which function in called. In your case it might be global scope **window**. You can use `bind` method.

```
axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
    .then(function (response) {
      alert(response.data)
      var result = response.data
      console.log("result out :"+result)
      this.setState({propval : result})
      this.propfun(response.data)
      self.forceUpdate()
    }.bind(this))
```

Or if your using **es6** then you can also use **arrow** function

```
 axios.post('/eventcreate/createevent', data)
    .then((response) => {
      alert(response.data)
      var result = response.data
      console.log("result out :"+result)
      this.setState({propval : result})
      this.propfun(response.data)
      self.forceUpdate()
    })
```